# C# - multiple if else statement does not work correctly

Tags: c#, mysql, if-statement

I am using .net connector for mysql. I went to code a user login form, that seems to work correctly, but when i click the login button with valid login details, it tells me i logged in successfully then tells me its a wrong user/pass combo.

here is the code and everything seems the way it should be.

The program checks the hashed password against the one entered in the database, which all works nicely. But for some reason the "successfully logged in" messagebox shows then right after, the "wrong username/password combo" messagebox shows.

I've been trying to figure out where i went wrong for the past 2 days and its drivin me nuts. maybe you guys can see where i screwed up lol

the code:

```
            try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            command.CommandText = "select * from users";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                listBox4.Items.Add(ex);
                MessageBox.Show("There has been an error connecting to the user database! Please try again later.");
            }
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                if (textBox4.Text == Reader.GetString(2))
                {
                    string haspass= CryptorEngine.Encrypt(textBox5.Text, true);
                    if (haspass == Reader.GetString(3))
                    {
                            MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Unhashed Username/Password Combination");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username/Password Combination");
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listBox4.Items.Add(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you do the filtering in the SQL query (`where` clause). You can check the  number of returned rows using `reader.HasRows`

Comment: no, the first if statement checks if the username exists in the database, and if it does, it checks the password. if the username does not exists, it shows the "Wrong Username/Password Combination" message

Comment: What returned by `select * from users`?

Comment: might be because of the while(Reader.Read()) when reading is not done yet, the if statement might occur again. you might want to include a return option after the messagebox appearing

Comment: every user in the database is returned from select * from users (which equals 2. me and a test user). As far as the were clause, im abit new to c# + mysql so im still trying to grasp the code.

Comment: @moonlight, didnt think of that, I'll go try that now

Comment: ok, moonlight helped me solve this one, going on the idea that the reader is not done reading, i added "connection.Close();" after the user gets the "login successful" message, and viola! no more double messageboxes. thanks for the help

Comment: be aware that you probably only check the first username-password combination, when having multiple users you might want to use an answer from below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a better way to do it:

```
try
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader Reader;
    //Change the "username" and "password" to the corresponding names of these columns in your table
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password LIMIT 1";
    //assuming textbox4 has the username
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox4.Text); 
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", CryptorEngine.Encrypt(textBox5.Text, true));

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        listBox4.Items.Add(ex);
        MessageBox.Show("There has been an error connecting to the user database! Please try again later.");
        //you should return here since if there's no connection you can't run the query
    }

    Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if(Reader.HasRows){
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username/Password Combination");
    }

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    listBox4.Items.Add(ex);
}
```

This will only return one row (if it exists).

Comment: Yes, but it will still scan the whole table. Better to use an `EXISTS` clause combined with `LIMIT` to return the first available result only.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas I know about the `LIMIT` but not the `EXISTS`, Care to explain ? also, thanks for the suggestion, I updated the solution with `LIMIT`.

Comment: I've updated my post with an explanation, although you 're certainly better off going to the source (the link to MySQL Reference material). Cheers!

Comment: @Ioannis Karadimas: It won't scan the table if there is an index on the username that covers password or is clustered.    To add to this answer, I would also hash the password and have a column for a salt. One should almost never store a password in a way that someone could read it out if they had full access to the data. Personally, SHA512 with a GUID for a salt.

Comment: @Bengie: It wont scan the table, but using EXISTS will not even completely scan the index, therefore it's potentially faster still. As far as the salt is concerned, I agree that it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if your `DataReader` is returning more than one result, the code drops into the successful path for the first result then the unsuccessful path for the second result.

You need to make your SQL more specific, instead of querying for all users `select * from users` you should only query for the details of the user who is curently attempting to log-in, something like (pseudo-code) -

`select * from users where username = yourusernamefield`

Where the `yourusernamefield` value was taken from your form. You would need protect against SQL injection by passing the username field as a parameter to your query.

Comment: This would be prone to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: You should never hardcode a where in a sql string. Rich is absolutely right that this is prone to a SQL injection. Because your system knows who the user is therefore all conditional checks must be part of the application security and not database security. If you know what I mean.

Comment: while not exactly my fix for this, i am going to implement this. thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the SQL string in my answer is pseudo-code. You should use a full solution like the one given in Nacereddine's answer to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping through each user in the table, of course there will be a user whose credentials do not match.

Try adding the credentials to your query eg:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from users where username = ?username AND password = ?password";
IDbDataParameter usernameParameter = _command.CreateParameter();
usernameParameter.ParameterName = "?username";
usernameParameter.Value = username;
command.Parameters.Add(usernameParameter);
IDbDataParameter passwordParameter = _command.CreateParameter();
passwordParameter .ParameterName = "?password";
passwordParameter .Value = password;
command.Parameters.Add(passwordParameter);
```

Then if you find a match, you know that the credentials are correct.

As an aside, you may not be closing your connection if an exception is thrown before you call `connection.Close()`, consider adding the `Close` call inside a finally block, or use your connection within a using block like so:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are querying **all** users, and testing all of them, and messaging on each. You should restrict the original `select` with a `where` on the username, if possible.

As an observation, in an ideal scenario you would have a "salt" on the user record, and use that in the hash (to prevent breaking via a rainbow table, or other non-user-specific methods). For example, if this was me, I would have something like (using "dapper" syntax for brevity):

```
string name = ... // whichever text.Text
string pw = ...
var row = connection.Query("select Salt, Hash from Users where Username = @name",
          new {name}).SingleOrDefault();
bool loggedIn = false;
if(row != null)
{
    byte[] salt = row.Salt, hash = row.Hash;
    loggedIn = BlobsAreEqual(CryptorEngine.Encrypt(pw, salt, true), hash);
}
// maybe add random wait here, to slow down brute-force
if(loggedIn) {
   // great!
} else {
   // increment failed counter, and potentially lock out account
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an immediate solution, you should return right after your successful message. What seems to be happening is that you iterate through the users, encountering first the correct user account, then in the next iteration, another user.

To properly tackle the problem you could replace your code with the following:

```
try
{
    using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
    using(MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT * from users 
                WHERE USERNAME = @Username AND Password = @Password
                LIMIT 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";

        try { connection.Open(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            listBox4.Items.Add(ex);
            MessageBox.Show("There has been an error connecting to the user database! Please try again later.");
        }

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox4.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", 
            CryptorEngine.Encrypt(textBox5.Text, true));

        Successful = (int) command.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
        MessageBox.Show(Successful
            ? "Successfully logged in!"
            : "Wrong Username/Password Combination");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    listBox4.Items.Add(ex);
}
```

The code above limits the query to a single result and allows you to use the connector's parameterization facilities to both avoid a potential SQL Injection attack and assert the user's identity quickly.

EDIT: 
[EXISTS documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

EXISTS answers whether a given subquery returns results, or not. I use it to ensure the query is as optimized as possible, and to avoid a table scan. `EXISTS` will ignore the select list in subqueries, and will return as soon as it can determine that any results can be obtained for the given subquery. `LIMIT` is probably redundant in this example but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Quick but bad solution. What if you have a million users in your database, your login will die unless you provide conditional filtering before you try and search the database.

Comment: I agree totally. That's why I provided a more complete solution with my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

With these two lines:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from users";

while (Reader.Read())
{

}
```

You are reading **all** of the users back from the database and looping over all the returned items. You then have:

```
if (textBox4.Text == Reader.GetString(2))
{
    ....
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username/Password Combination");
}
```

With this code you will print out the "Wrong Username/Password" message for every user that's not the one you typed into the input box.

You could either just look for the specific user entered into the form:

```
command.CommandText = "select * from users where username = @username";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox4.Text);
```

or just print a single error message:

```
bool loggedIn = false;
while (Reader.Read())
{
    if (textBox4.Text == Reader.GetString(2))
    {
        string haspass= CryptorEngine.Encrypt(textBox5.Text, true);
        if (haspass == Reader.GetString(3))
        {
            loggedIn = true;
        }
    }
}

if (loggedIn)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Unhashed Username/Password Combination");
}
```

Though you could structure this better.

In fact if you send both username and password down you can do the check in one go. If there is no user of that name or the password is incorrect there'll be no results returned, but if the combination is correct there'll be exactly one result and you'll know that the user is valid without having to do any further checking.

Answer (score 0):

In code you have: `command.CommandText = "select * from users"` so for each user in database you're trying to login. Probaly there are 2 users and your login data are ok for one of them. You should return from function just after success and show failed only when none of users succed.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over all users. The credentials match for the first one and you can "log in" and the next one fails.